# Convert a `while` loop to a `for` loop

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I'm new in C, and not sure if my loop is correctly converted.

```
while(a<b--)
{
    do
    {
        d+=a++;
    }
    while(a!=c);
    c+=a&b;
 }
```

and it's my loop

```
for( ; a<b ; b--)
{
    d += a++;
    for( ; a != c ; a++)
    {
        c+= a&b
    }   
}
```

I know it's maybe easy and stupid, but I hope you'll help me :)
Thx

Comment: No, `b--` at the wrong time.

Comment: Just run it and see if you still get the same answers...

Comment: @takendarkk: In a language sprikled with potential for undefined behaviour like C this is bad advise.

Comment: Is better advice to try nothing and post here?

Comment: So... can anyone write it correctly?

Comment: I don't know.  What do you use to test it?

Comment: SO is not a test and verification house.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be something like this :

```
for(;a<b--;){ 
for(d += a++ ; a != c ; )
{
  d += a++; 
}    
c+= a&b
}
```

The above logic works !

I ran both programs as below and they output the same result :

Program1:[derived from your program 1]

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

int a=10,b=10,c=10,d=10;

while(a<b--)
{
do
{
    d+=a++;
}
while(a!=c);
c+=a&b;
}
printf("a=%d\tb=%d\tc=%d\td=%d",a,b,c,d);
}
```

And it outputs this :

```
a=10    b=9 c=10    d=10
```

Similarly the changed Program2 :[As requested]

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

int a=10,b=10,c=10,d=10;

for(;a<b--;){
for(d += a++ ; a != c ; )
{
d += a++;
}
c+= a&b;
}
printf("a=%d\tb=%d\tc=%d\td=%d",a,b,c,d);
}
```

And it outputs the same :

```
a=10    b=9 c=10    d=10
```

Comment: This post-increments `a++` at first, then twice in the loop. The question's `while` loop increments `a` only once in the loop.

Comment: Where is condition a<b-- ?

Comment: oops...forgot that...wait

Comment: for (;a<b;b--)
{
    for (;a!=c;)
    {
        d+=a++;
    }
    c+=a&b;
}

Comment: @Krejw: Check the post

Comment: `for(;a<b--;){  ... }}` unbalanced `{}`.  Would benefit with more classic formatting.